# Clojure count resource use

Tags: performance, clojure

Different infinite loops (at the REPL, clojure 1.7.0):

```
(count (range)) ; ~100% of 1 CPU, as expected.
(def x (range))
(count x) ; Over 7 CPUs maxed out, on a 4-core machine (hyper threading?).
```

The lower loop also hogs memory, so incessant GC may be the reason for the huge CPU usage. But why would there be such a memory difference in the first place?

Comment: `count` does not retain data while it counts. But with `def` the materialized data is retained by the `x` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `range` creates a lazy sequence.  Lazy sequences create their elements only on-demand.  If the beginning of the lazy seq is tied to some variable (either locally with `let` or globally with `def`), the seq will cache all its elements and thus consume memory.  This is commonly referred to as "holding onto the head of a sequence".

That's why your second example consumes a lot of memory.

I would expect that an analysis with jvisualvm will show that it is not clojure itself that consumes the CPU cycles but the JVM trying to cope with the increasing memory usage.

Finally, `count` traverses the whole sequence, thereby realizing all elements.  In case of just `(range)` the sequence would never end, it gets stopped when no more memory is available.

Comment: @KevinKostlan because a sequence may produce an element that contains, say, current time. Which means that if you don't store materialized data then the second iteration over *the same* sequence would produce different results.